# How to use Tensorflow embeddings in scikit learn models?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am to trying to use `text data` for `linear regression model` as `input` and `converting my text data to vectors using Universal sentence encoder` from `tensorflow hub` as pretrained model for this but this gives me `tf.tensors` and now I am not able to split the data into training and testing for scikit learn linear regression model as my target feature is continuous.

`This gives me embeddings (i.e vectors of shape (1,512) for each text in my pandas dataframe text column)`

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5'
model = hub.load(model_url)
embeddings = model(train['excerpt'])
```

This is how data look :

```
         id                  excerpt                                  target    
0   c12129c31   When the young people returned to the ballroom...   -0.340259   
1   85aa80a4c   All through dinner time, Mrs. Fayre was somewh...   -0.315372   
2   b69ac6792   As Roger had predicted, the snow departed as q...   -0.580118   
3   dd1000b26   And outside before the palace a great garden w...   -1.054013   
4   37c1b32fb   Once upon a time there were Three Bears who li...   0.247197
```

This is how embeddings look:

```
tf.Tensor: shape=(2834, 512), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.06747025,  0.02054032, -0.01223458, ...,  0.03468879,
        -0.04216784,  0.01212691],
       [-0.01053216,  0.01346854,  0.01992477, ...,  0.03078162,
        -0.0226634 ,  0.04429556],
       [-0.10778417,  0.01735378,  0.00803178, ...,  0.00345916,
         0.00552441, -0.02448413],
       ...,
       [ 0.0364146 ,  0.02996029, -0.06757646, ..., -0.00335971,
        -0.01381749, -0.08319554],
       [ 0.0042374 ,  0.02291174, -0.04473154, ..., -0.02009053,
        -0.00428826, -0.06476445],
       [-0.0141812 ,  0.03879716,  0.03304171, ...,  0.06709221,
        -0.05016331,  0.00868828]], dtype=float32)
```

Now I want to use this embeddings as input in Linear Regression model or any Regression model using scikit learn. But not able to split the data using `train_test_split()`, giving me error `TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([1434, 2653, 2620, ...,  749, 2114, 2389])`

This is how I am splitting the data:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(embeddings,train['target'],test_size =0.2, shuffle =True)
```

Comment: It seems like you are giving the wrong data type can you also add the data display that you are splitting?

Comment: Instead of giving your output values as train["target"], have you tried to give it as train["target"].values? It seems like the problem is in that part because since you are giving it as train["target"] you are providing pandas Series which consists Series index besides values.

Comment: same issue even after using train['target'].values, looks like it is the issue of embeddings format

Comment: Have you tried this `X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(embeddings.numpy(),train['target'].to_numpy(),test_size =0.2, shuffle =True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `train_test_split` you are passing a tensor. Instead, you should pass the NumPy array like this-

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(embeddings.numpy(), train['target'],test_size =0.2, shuffle =True)
```